# Order of capture in lambda capture

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

C++14 allows initializing variable in capture clause (init-capture).

But why the compiler allows **capture all by reference** followed by **init-capture** but doesn't allow **init-capture** followed by **capture all by reference**?

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    std::jthread t([&, count = 0]() mutable {   /* Compiles OK */
    //std::jthread t([count = 0, &]() mutable {   /* Produce ERROR */
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        while(count < x)
        {
            ++count;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
            std::cout << ".";
        }
        std::cout << "\nDone." << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Why the compiler enforces this order of capture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just syntax. The captures specification in a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) can contain two things:

1. an optional capture-default (one of `=` or `&`), followed by
2. a comma-separated list of zero or more captures.

The syntax just requires the capture-default to appear before the rest of the captures. Nothing more.

See [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#nt:lambda-capture) for the full specification in the standard.

Answer (score 4):

It is by the definition of the language grammar of the capture

```
lambda-capture:
    capture-default
    capture-list
    capture-default , capture-list
```

Otherwise it will be not easy to distinguish an erroneous capture from a valid capture.

Comment: Standard link for reference: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#nt:lambda-capture